# What does the 'Game Completed' cheat do in Shining Force 2?

Tags: shining-force-2

In Shining Force 2 you can trigger cheats by doing a button combination during the title screen. Then you get some cheat options:

- Turbo Mode
- Control Enemy
- Game Completed

What does **Game Completed** do? I've tried selecting it and it seems as though it doesn't change the gameplay at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by the name of this cheat. When selecting "Game Completed" in configuration mode, you can access a bunch of options that are normally available only when you have finished the game. Those are :

- Expert mode : after you reset the console, higher difficulties will be available.
- Name All characters : after you reset the console > start a new game > name your character > highlight "Exit" on the character name screen > Press **A + Start** > another Character appears (whose name can be changed) > Repeat until you're done
- Enable the sound test : after you reset the console > highlight a saved game file and quickly hold **Start + Up + C**

In the end nothing truly usefull but at least now you know. More tips: [here](http://www.gamewinners.com/GEN/ShiningForce2.htm)